# Numeric string validation in c#

Tags: c#, string, boolean, tryparse

I'm trying to validate if the 'columnsValidation' is a numeric string, and convert it to    an int, if so.

For some reason, I end up in an endless loop, because 'isNumber' always equals false...

This code is part of my lottery project.

I hope that my question is clear enough, if additional information is needed just tell me and I'll answer.

Thanks in advance,
Ilan.

```
Console.WriteLine("Please insert the number of rows: ");

        string columnsValidation = Console.ReadLine();

        bool isNumber = false;

            while(isNumber == false)
            {
                bool.TryParse(columnsValidation, out isNumber);
                if (isNumber == true)
                    columns = int.Parse(columnsValidation);
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You've inserted an invalid value, please try again.");
                    columnsValidation = Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Your code looking for `true` as input...

Comment: bool.TryParse tries to get a bool out of 'true' or 'false' and tells you nothing about if columsValidaton is a number.

Comment: The way you are using `bool.TryParse` is incorrect. If you aren't going to use it's output, then you might as well use `bool.Parse(columnsValidation)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `int.TryParse` with `columnsValidation`

```
if (!int.TryParse(columnsValidation,out columns)
{
     Console.WriteLine("You've inserted an invalid value, please try again.");
     columnsValidation = Console.ReadLine();
}
else
{ 
    isNumber = true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Correct your usage of `TryParse`:

```
isNumber = int.TryParse(columnsValidation, out columns);
```

`TryParse` returns boolean indicating whether the parsing succeeded, and in case of success sets `out` param with the parsing result.

Answer (score 0):

Why not you use `Int.TryParse`

```
int columns = 0;

while(true)
{
    if (!Int32.TryParse(columnsValidation,out columns)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You've inserted an invalid value, please try again.");
        columnsValidation = Console.ReadLine();
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}
```